# SVF model derivative downloaded as an (almost) empty ZIP file (Autodesk Forge)

Tags: node.js, autodesk-forge, autodesk-model-derivative

I have been a happy developer on Autodesk Forge these recent months, and have been able to perform several tasks using the API's.

However, I can't seem to be able to download SVF model derivatives properly (derived either from IFC or RVT files). I've tried the direct [curl](https://developer.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/reference/http/urn-manifest-derivativeurn-GET/) command or the forge-apis NPM package, without success. Oddly the download works fine, but all I get is a ZIP file with empty directories ("geometry", "material", "scene"), and (non-empty) "manifest.json" and "metadata.json" files.

I use a two-legged authentication process to generate the token (the files are on my Forge developer's account, not on A360 or BIM360). I am able to view the files with the 3D viewer, so the conversion from RVT or IFC to SVF works nicely.

I also tried the https://extract.autodesk.io model extractor, but this doesn't allow me to retrieve the derivative either ("Cannot GET /extracted/2836276-AC11-Institute-Var-2-IFCifc.zip").

Any idea? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for the inconvenience, the issue was that I assumed the latest version was set to 2.15 while it is still set as 2.10.
The codefix to force version 2.15 has been pushed live.

Comment: Thank you @cyrille, I have downloaded the latest version of extract.autodesk.io and it works fine. As stated in my initial post, I still have issues when simply attempting to download an SVF derivative through forge-apis (or even via the basic curl command), but I'll check your extract.autodesk.io source files to get an idea on how to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue recently, we got some of the issues reported and have already reported to the owner who unfortunately is on vacation now.

I debugged into the code and find that the issue is related to the new added file "wgs.min.js" which was added recently at commit of Jun 16, 2017. Because the project is still using the version of 2.10, unfortunately, there is no 2.10 version of "wgs.min.js" online when it tries to get from https://developer.api.autodesk.com/viewingservice/v1/viewers/wgs.min.js?v=2.10 (2.11 ~ 2.15 are there), this made it fail to package the zip file, so you will get a 404 error downloading the bubbles.

To get the bubble for now, I suggest you to setup a local server from https://github.com/cyrillef/extract.autodesk.io using the version on March 24, 2017. I verified it, should be working good. Or if it's urgent, you can send me the source file and I can help generate the bubbles for you. Let me know.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your quick reply. I will do as suggested for the mean time (installing extract.autodesk.io), hoping that the bug will be fixed soon.

Comment: Yes, we will keep tracking on this internally, and if the solution helps, could you please mark it as solution, thanks.

Comment: I have tried the extract.autodesk.io locally but that doesn't work either (some files are generated/downloaded but not the main ones, namely the svf and other object files). Anyway, on the long term I am mostly interested in the CURL-like or forge-apis approach since I would like to download the SVF files programmatically and not "manually" with an User Interface, for each new bubble. Thanks.

Comment: Which files have the problem? Maybe you can check the network and try it again, remember to use the version on March 24, 2017. It worked on my side Ok, and I also suggested to some other partners, it seems working fine too. About the request, yes, as I know, it's already submitted to our engineering team, but I do not have have a time schedule for that yet.

Comment: FYI I cannot extract the following file: https://extract.autodesk.io/explore/2836276-AC11-Institute-Var-2-IFCifc. I will wait for the request to be treated. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: The issue was fixed by https://github.com/cyrillef/extract.autodesk.io/commit/f51b304ba96d7eb00e18f84d536190b67c285ea8 , and it uses the version of 2.15 now. I just verified it, it works fine as expect, please try.

Comment: I have tested the new version posted by Cyrille and it works fine. Thanks for the follow up!